Windows Starting Multiple Processes
This is very strange, and I'm somewhat out of ideas! One of our users (on Windows 11) has reported that starting our application from the desktop shortcut creates multiple instances of the exe process. Our exe is single-instance only and checks for this - so every time the users starts it complains that the exe is already running...which it technically is. However, if we launch the process from a batch file using 'start', we don't see this issue.
This occurs whether the user double-clicks our shortcut, right-click-opens it or even double clicks on one of our files to start via file association. Is anyone aware of a Windows functionality that might cause multiple process instances to start like this? We haven't update our software in the time frame of this problem occurring...and it was previously operating correctly. We are questioning if it could be a Windows Update thing, or some other software...but we've never encountered anything like this.
Anyone got any ideas?

Possible workaround: use a shortcut to something similar to the following in a .bat file.
@echo off
tasklist | findstr "<my_app.exe>"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
if %errorlevel% equ 1 start " " "C:\Program Files\<My_Folder>\<my_app.exe>"
exit

:running
"C:\Program Files\NirSoft\nircmd.exe" win activate process "<my_app.exe>"
exit

The shortcut can be set to run hidden. The use of nircmd.exe is optional; all it does is bring the already-running app to the front. Simply omit that one line if you don't care to use that third-party tool.

Thanks. Our "single-instance check" already brings the running app to the front, provided the main Window can be found. Our workaround with a batch file is sufficient for the user at the moment....but I really like to know what the actually issue is rather than just whacking a plaster on it....
